# Creating a description of an item from an inventory

Tags: python, beginner, python-3.x, game

I'm really new to Python (like only a month of study) and I was testing out dictionaries, so I tried to make an 'inventory' where you can pick an item from your inventory and examine it. But I can tell that I'm not doing this in the most efficient or elegant way.

Originally I thought I could make each item its separate dictionary, kind of like this:

```
#define what's in your inventory using a list
inventory = ["apple", "tire"]

#create a list of items with attributes using dictionaries
apple = {
    "name":"apple",
    "type":"fruit",
    "edible":"edible",
    "color":"red",
}

tire = {
    "name":"tire",
    "type":"object",
    "edible":"not edible",
    "color":"grey"
}

#explain the program to the user
print("Choose an item to examine. Items in your inventory are:")
print(*inventory, sep = ", ")

#set the loop to true
itemsloop = True

#begin the loop
while itemsloop == True:
    #ask for user input
    x = input()
```

But then I got stuck at the part where it's time to take the input and match it to the name of a dictionary, because one is a string and one isn't. The following code is working, but feels... inelegant and unnecessary to type out (prefix)-name, (prefix)-type, (prefix)-edible for every entry. I feel like there must be a simpler way to accomplish this that I'm just not seeing because I don't think like a programmer yet. I don't know.

If you can explain any more efficient methods with simple terminology (again, huge newbie not just to Python but programming in general), I'd really appreciate it!

```
#define what's in your inventory using a list
inventory = ["apple", "tire"]

#create a list of items with attributes using a dictionary
items = {
    "apple-name":"apple",
    "apple-type":"fruit",
    "apple-edible":"edible",
    "apple-color":"red",

    "tire-name":"tire",
    "tire-type":"object",
    "tire-edible":"not edible",
    "tire-color":"grey"
}

#explain the program to the user
print("Choose an item to examine. Items in your inventory are:")
print(*inventory, sep = ", ")

#set the loop to true
itemsloop = True

#begin the loop
while itemsloop == True:
    #ask for user input
    x = input()

    if x in inventory:
        #if the input matches something you have, find the attributes of
        #the item in the inventory and print them.
        print("This is a " + items[x + "-color"] + " " + 
        items[x + "-name"] + ", a type of " + items[x + "-type"] 
        + ". It is " + items[x + "-edible"] + ".")
    elif x == "quit":
        #if the player wishes to quit, end the program.
        itemsloop == False
        break
    else:
        #if the item is not recognized, let the player know.
        print("You don't have that in your inventory.")
```

(The sample output would be something like, "This is a red apple, a type of fruit. It is edible.")

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To expand on [the answer](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/207618/98493) given by [@Aries_is_there](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/users/141774/aries-is-there) in, you should indeed make your dictionary a nested dictionary with the item names as first keys and the item properties as keys of the sub dictionaries.

You should also be aware that `x in inventory` is \$\mathcal{O}(n)\$ if `inventory` is a list, but this is mitigated when making it a dictionary, because `x in items` is \$\mathcal{O}(1)\$ for dictionaries.

Your printing can also be simplified by using an [`f-string`](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0498/).

I would also add a [`if __name__ == "__main__"`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/419163/what-does-if-name-main-do) guard to allow importing functions form this script from another script.

And finally, Python has an official style-guide, [PEP8](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/), which is well worth a read. You are already mostly following it, except for the missing spaces after the `:` in your dictionaries.

```
items = {"apple": {"name": "apple",
                   "type": "fruit",
                   "edible": "edible",
                   "color": "red"},
         "tire": {"name":"tire",
                  "type":"object",
                  "edible":"not edible",
                  "color":"grey"}}

if __name__ == "__main__":
    print("Choose an item to examine. Items in your inventory are:")
    print(*items.keys(), sep = ", ")

    while True:
        x = input()

        if x in inventory:
            #if the input matches something you have, find the attributes of
            #the item in the inventory and print them.
            item = items[x]
            print(f"This is a {item['color']} {item['name']}, a type of {item['type']}. It is {item['edible']}.")
        elif x == "quit":
            #if the player wishes to quit, end the program.
            break
        else:
            #if the item is not recognized, let the player know.
            print("You don't have that in your inventory.")
```

You could take it one level further by making it object-oriented. In this case you would probably want an `Object` class for which you define the [magic `__str__` method](https://www.python-course.eu/python3_magic_methods.php), which controls what happens if you do `print(x)`.

```
class Object:
    def __init__(self, name, type="object", edible=False, color=None):
        self.name = name
        self.type = type
        self.edible = edible
        self.color = color

    def __str__(self):
        s = ["This is a "]
        if self.color is not None:
            s.append(self.color + " ")
        s.extend([self.name, f", a type of {self.type}."]
        s.append(f"It is {'not ' if not self.edible else ''}edible.")
        return "".join(s)


items = {"apple": Object("apple", "fruit", edible=True, color="red"),
         "tire": Object("tire", color="grey")}


if __name__ == "__main__":
    print("Choose an item to examine. Items in your inventory are:")
    print(*items.keys(), sep = ", ")

    while True:
        x = input()

        if x in items:
            #if the input matches something you have, find the attributes of
            #the item in the inventory and print them.
            item = 
            print(items[x])
        elif x == "quit":
            #if the player wishes to quit, end the program.
            break
        else:
            #if the item is not recognized, let the player know.
            print("You don't have that in your inventory.")
```

Comment: Thank you very much for the thorough explanation. I didn't know you could nest dictionaries! I'm still new to a lot of the things included in your post, so i will be doing googling for a while, haha. Do you have any recommendations on a good newbie explanation for magic methods? I had never heard of those.

Answer (score 3):

As you use item's `name` to search the item `information`, so you can design the `name` as the key of `items` hash table.

```
items = {
    "apple":
        {
            #type, edible,color information
        },
    ...
}
```

Comment: I didn't understand that you could use dictionaries as dictionary keys. Thank you.

Comment: haha as long as you get @Graipher answer, he did a good explain

Comment: @Red You actually can't. But you *can* use them as dictionary values. If you want to use them as keys you would have to convert the dictionary into a tuple of `key, value` tuples first, so it is hashable. This would be sensitive to the order then, though.